# How to efficiently slice numpy arrays? (Finite difference method)

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am trying to use the finite difference method with NumPy arrays, but the slicing is incredibly slow. It's not viable to use lists as I am applying math operations. Using matlab, equivalent code is executed in 2 seconds whilst the python code finishes executing for over 1 minute. My python code is:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate 

def heston_explicit_nonuniform(S,V,K,T,Ns,Nv,kappa,theta,rho,sigma,r,q,dt,dv,ds):
    
    U = np.empty((Ns,Nv))
    
    for s in range(Ns):
        for v in range(Nv):
            U[s,v] = np.maximum( S[s] - K , 0)
        
 
    for t in range(Nt - 1):
        
        
        for v in range(Nv-1):
            U[0,v] = 0
            U[Ns-1,v] = np.maximum( Smax - K ,0)
            
        for s in range(Ns):
           
            U[s,Nv-1] = np.maximum(S[s] - K, 0)

        u = np.copy(U)
  

        for s in range(1,Ns-1):
            derV = (u[s,1] - u[s,0]) / (V[1] - V[0]) 
            derS = (u[s+1,0] - u[s-1,0]) / (S[s+1]-S[s-1])
            U[s,0] = u[s,0] + dt * ( -r*u[s,0] + (r-q) * S[s] * derS + kappa*theta*derV) 
   
        
        u = np.copy(U)
        
        for s in range(1,Ns-1):
            
            for v in range(1,Nv-1):
                derS = 0.5*(u[s+1,v] - u[s-1,v]) / (S[s+1] - S[s-1])
                derV = 0.5*(u[s,v+1] - u[s,v-1]) / (V[v+1] - V[v-1])
                derSS = (u[s+1,v] - 2*u[s,v] + u[s-1,v]) / ( (S[s+1] - S[s])*(S[s]-S[s-1]))
                derVV = (u[s,v+1] - 2*u[s,v] + u[s,v-1]) / ( (V[v+1] - V[v])*(V[v]-V[v-1]))
                derSV = (u[s+1,v+1] + u[s-1,v-1] - u[s-1,v+1] - u[s+1,v-1]) \
                    / (4 * (S[s+1] - S[s-1]) * (V[v+1] - V[v-1]))
                A = 0.5 * V[v] * (S[s]**2) * derSS 
                B = rho*sigma*V[v]*S[s] *derSV
                C = 0.5*(sigma**2)*V[v]*derVV
                D = 0.5*(r-q)*S[s]*derS
                E = kappa*(theta-V[v])*derV
                L = dt * (A + B + C + D + E - r*u[s,v])
                U[s,v] = L + u[s,v]
      
        if t %100==0:
            print(t)
            
  
    return U

Vmax=0.5
Vmin=0
Smin=0
T=0.15

K=100.
Smax = 2*K

Vmax=0.5

r= 0.02
q=0.05
rho=-0.9
v0=0.05
sigma=0.3
kappa=1.5
theta=0.04
L=17
Nv=39

Ns=79

Nt = 3000

dt = T/Nt

Vi = np.linspace(0,Vmax,Nv)
Si = np.linspace(0,Smax,Ns)
dv = (Vmax-Vmin)/Nv    
ds = (Smax-Smin)/Ns  
  
call = heston_explicit_nonuniform(Si,Vi,K,T,Ns,Nv,kappa,theta,rho,sigma,r,q,dt,dv,ds)

data = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(Si,Vi,call)


z_new = data(101.52,0.05412)
print('FDM: ', z_new[0,0])
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'slicing'. Are you referring to the `s` and `v` for loops? Python/numpy does not  have any `jit` compilation of iteration like this, so, yes, it will be slow compare to MATLAB.  You need to figure out how to rework those loops to work with 'whole arrays', which is commonly called 'vectorizing'.

Comment: Have you tried using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)? If I edit your example by adding `@numba.njit()` right before this function, the execution time drops to 80 milliseconds

Comment: @NickODell if you already did recreate and fix the issue, I think you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, there is no slicing in your code. Which is what is missing.

In numpy, you compute things on whole arrays, not elements by elements.
In other words, you need to avoid `for` loops, that are pure python (and therefore very slow: the only reason python is quite fast when using numpy, is because most of the CPU time is spend in C code, not in python code).

So for example, to focus on a specific and quite easy part of your code, this loop

```py
for s in range(1,Ns-1):
    derV = (u[s,1] - u[s,0]) / (V[1] - V[0]) 
    derS = (u[s+1,0] - u[s-1,0]) / (S[s+1]-S[s-1])
    U[s,0] = u[s,0] + dt * ( -r*u[s,0] + (r-q) * S[s] * derS + kappa*theta*derV)
```

should not exist (or, to be more accurate, it should exist only in numpy's internal code, in C)
what you do here, is, for each s between 1 and Ns-1, you compute `derV`, that is a combination of **s***th* element of 2 vectors (`u[:,1]` and `u[:,0]`, so 2 columns of `u`) and a scalar (`V[1]-V[0]`).

So, all together that is `Ns-2` computation for 2 `Ns-2` vectors. You can let numpy do that

```
derV = (u[1:-1,1] - u[1:-1,0) / (V[1]-V[0])
```

And now, `derV` is an array of the `Ns-2` value you compute

So this part of the code can be turned into

```
derV = (u[1:-1,1] - u[1:-1,0) / (V[1]-V[0])
for s in range(1,Ns-1):
    derS = (u[s+1,0] - u[s-1,0]) / (S[s+1]-S[s-1])
    U[s,0] = u[s,0] + dt * ( -r*u[s,0] + (r-q) * S[s] * derS + kappa*theta*derV[s-1])
```

So we have "vectorized" the computation of the `Ns-2` `derV` value

Likewise

```
derS = (u[2:,0] - u[:-2,0]) / (S[2:]-S[:-2])
```

So

```
derV = (u[1:-1,1] - u[1:-1,0) / (V[1]-V[0])
derS = (u[2:,0] - u[:-2,0]) / (S[2:]-S[:-2])
for s in range(1,Ns-1):
    U[s,0] = u[s,0] + dt * ( -r*u[s,0] + (r-q) * S[s] * derS[s-1] + kappa*theta*derV[s-1])
```

And that last iterated computation, `U[s,0]` is also just `Ns-2` independant computations, from the `Ns-2` `u[s,0]` values, the `Ns-2` `derS` values, the `Ns-2` `derV` values, the `Ns-2` `S` values, and some scalars.

So it can also be turned into

```
derV = (u[1:-1,1] - u[1:-1,0) / (V[1]-V[0])
derS = (u[2:,0] - u[:-2,0]) / (S[2:]-S[:-2])
U[1:-1,0] += dt * ( -r*u[1:-1,0] + (r-q) * S[1:-1] * derS + kappa*theta*derV)
```

If I continue this for your whole code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate 

def heston_explicit_nonuniform(S,V,K,T,Ns,Nv,kappa,theta,rho,sigma,r,q,dt,dv,ds):
    
    U = np.empty((Ns,Nv))
    U[:,:] = np.maximum(S-K, 0)[:,None]
        
 
    for t in range(Nt - 1):
        U[0,:]=0
        U[Ns-1,:] = np.maximum(Smax-K,0)
        U[:,Nv-1] = np.maximum(S-K,0)
            

        u=U.copy()

        derV=(u[1:-1,1]-u[1:-1,0])/(V[1]-V[0])
        derS=(u[2:,0]-u[:-2,0])/(S[2:]-S[:-2])
        U[1:-1,0] = u[1:-1,0] + dt*(-r*u[1:-1,0] + (r-q)*S[1:-1] * derS + kappa*theta*derV)
        
        u = U.copy()
        
        derS = 0.5*(u[2:,1:-1] - u[:-2,1:-1]) / (S[2:]-S[:-2])[:,None]
        derV = 0.5*(u[1:-1,2:]-u[1:-1,:-2]) / (V[2:]-V[:-2])[None,:]
        derSS = (u[2:,1:-1]-2*u[1:-1,1:-1]+u[:-2,1:-1]) / ((S[2:]-S[1:-1]) * (S[1:-1]-S[:-2]))[:,None]
        derVV = (u[1:-1,2:]-2*u[1:-1,1:-1]+u[1:-1,:-2]) / ((V[2:]-V[1:-1]) * (V[1:-1]-V[:-2]))[None,:]
        derSV = (u[2:,2:] + u[:-2,:-2] - u[:-2, 2:] - u[2:,:-2]) \
               / 4 / (S[2:]-S[:-2])[:,None] / (V[2:]-V[:-2])[None,:]
        A = 0.5*V[None,1:-1] * (S[1:-1,None]**2) * derSS
        B = rho*sigma*V[None,1:-1]*S[1:-1,None] * derSV
        C = 0.5*(sigma**2)*V[None,1:-1]*derVV
        D = 0.5*(r-q)*S[1:-1, None]*derS
        E = kappa*(theta-V[None,1:-1])*derV
        L = dt * (A+B+C+D+E- r*u[1:-1,1:-1])
        U[1:-1,1:-1] += L
      
    return U

Vmax=0.5
Vmin=0
Smin=0
T=0.15

K=100.
Smax = 2*K

Vmax=0.5

r= 0.02
q=0.05
rho=-0.9
v0=0.05
sigma=0.3
kappa=1.5
theta=0.04
L=17
Nv=39

Ns=79

Nt = 3000

dt = T/Nt

Vi = np.linspace(0,Vmax,Nv)
Si = np.linspace(0,Smax,Ns)
dv = (Vmax-Vmin)/Nv    
ds = (Smax-Smin)/Ns  
  
call = heston_explicit_nonuniform(Si,Vi,K,T,Ns,Nv,kappa,theta,rho,sigma,r,q,dt,dv,ds)

data = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(Si,Vi,call)


z_new = data(101.52,0.05412)
print('FDM: ', z_new[0,0])
```

It returns the exact same result (including the very last decimal place), because it is the exact same computation. Just, iterations are done inside numpy's internal code, not in python

Note that I haven't even tried to understand the algorithm. I just translated as a  I would any arrays handling. Because, all the computation I've rewritten were batches of Ns-2 or Nv-2 or (Ns-2)(Nv-2) independent computation (the order wasn't important)

It would probably be interesting to go deeper in the algorithm itself, not just its coding. For example, I am pretty sure, one at least of the two `copy()` could be avoided.

It would be harder (but probably not impossible) to also vectorize the `for t` loop. Because this loop is different: computation done at the **t***th* iteration is dependent on the result of the **(t-1)***th* iteration's result. Which was not the case for the `for s` and `for v` loops

That may be possible using cumulative operator (that allows to use, in some specific cases, numpy "vectorization", that is hijacking internal numpy's for loop to replace yours, even when each iteration depends on the previous one. For example, using `cumsum`, `cumprod`.
(Memory wise, that would imply to keep a big array of all values of all (t,s,v) combinations. But from your example, that would be hardly 10 millions values, which is really not a problem nowadays)

But still, without even making any effort to adapt to the problem, by simple translation of for loops into numpy batches computation, we already gained a ×100 factor (on my slow machine, it went from precisely 100 seconds to 1 second. It is not every day that I see cases where timing ratio computation are that obvious :-) )